# How to use Union using Inner Join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, union

I have a one to many relationship between `departments` and `users`.

Database Design:

[image: SC]

`users` has each own department and department has many `users`. I wanted to select all the `department_name` but I have a duplicate values of `department_name` I want to merge it into one so I planned to use UNION how can I implement this using Inner Join? This is my code so far.

SQL

```
SELECT D.department_name FROM users U
INNER JOIN departments D ON D.id = U.department_id;
```

Results:

[image: SC]

Comment: If you just want the department names, why are you joining with the users table?  Just `SELECT department_name FROM departments`.

Comment: @eggyal Because what I planned to do I will insert all the users belongs to that `department_name`. I'm gonna put this in my combo-box.

Comment: I think we might need a little more detail about these combo boxes, and how you're trying to construct them.  If you're selecting users (with their departments), you'd need the join but obviously each department could appear more than once.  If you want only departments, then you shouldn't be making the join.  It *might* be that your easiest solution is to perform two queries?  Hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: @eggyal What I'm trying to achieve I'm gonna select by `department_name` and insert all the related users based on selected `department_name` Is it possible? Because If I just `SELECT department_name FROM departments` when I tried to insert this. It doesn't have any users because I just select only the `department_name`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the distinct department names, you need to group the users into a comma separated values.

```
select d.department_name, group_concat(u.id) user_id_list
from departments d inner join users u on d.department_id = u.department_id
group by d.department_name
```